# How do I limit a string variable so that it can only take one of two Strings

Tags: java, variables

I have a class animal and one of the variables for this class is gender. I want to limit this variable so that it can only take the strings "m" (for male) or "f" (for female). This is the code I have so far

```
public class Animal {
    String gender;

    public animal(String gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Use an `enum`?.

Comment: fix your constructor name

Comment: Constructor name should be `Animal`, not `animal`, and the field should be `private final`.

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is to assert within your setter and throw (say) an `IllegalArgumentException` if the string is not as you'd expect ('M', 'F' and perhaps watch for a null as well. You may want to `trim()` your input too)

A better answer is to consider that *gender isn't a string* and you may wish to investigate [enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), or possibly a boolean representing male vs. female (I suggest this at the risk of opening myself to gender-bias criticism!)

Comment: Using the word "enumerations" can be confused with the [`Enumeration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html) interface. The Java Language Specification (JLS) never refers to an [*enum type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9) using that word.

Comment: LOL Gender bias: `private boolean smart; public boolean isMale() { return ! smart; } public boolean isFemale() { return smart; }`. Now *that* is gender bias. ;-) FYI, me male, but if reversed meaning of `smart`, it wouldn't be gender bias, but *chauvinistic*.

Comment: @Andres - that's a very good point re enumerations. Now amended

Answer (score 1):

If you really don't **need** it as a `String` then an `enum` is ideal:

```
enum Gender {
    Male, Female, Unknown;
}
public class Animal {

    Gender gender;

    public Animal(Gender gender) {
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public Gender getGender() {
        return gender;
    }
}
```

Comment: *"can only take the strings "m" (for male) or "f" (for female)"* would mean that `Unknown` is not an option, so that should be removed. Perhaps a null guard in the constructor would be appropriate.

Comment: @Andreas - I added the Unknown to demonstrate the flexibility of my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use enum it's good a solution:

```
public enum Gender {
 MALE, FEMALE;
 }  

 public class Animal {
  Gender gender;

public Animal(Gender gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

public Gender getGender() {
    return gender;
   }
 }
```

In your mainTest you can use it like this:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal boi   = new Animal(Gender.MALE);
    Animal babao = new Animal(Gender.FEMALE);

   System.out.println("Boi's gender is: " + boi.getGender());
   System.out.println("Babao's gender is: " + babao.getGender())
}
```

Output

```
 Boi's gender is MALE
 Babao's gender is FEMALE
```

Comment: What?!? You're keeping the `String gender` field, even after creating a `Gender` enum type? Why??? --- Oh, and `setGender()` won't compile like that.

Comment: @Andreas ola!! what do you think now?

Comment: That part's been fixed. The `main` method however won't compile, since the `Animal` constructor takes a `Gender`, not an animal name. That's also why there was no setter method in the question, unless you want to suggest doing sex change operations on animals.

Comment: @Andreas now is perfect ;)